# How to log in to Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, vps

I installed Tomcat on VPS with Ubuntu 16.04, everything works, but I can not log in. At the moment in the file `tomcat-users.xml` these are the settings:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd" version="1.0">

<role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager-gui"/>
 </tomcat-users>
```

I use `manager`, but I can not enter. Tell me what could be the problem? In the files manager and host-manager everything is configured, otherwise there would be another error. Location of tomcat-users: `/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

Contents of tomcat.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What error/message are you getting when trying to access manager?

Comment: I get no error, a new authorization window appears right away

Comment: In short, I have no idea what the problem was... I just reset everything to a new droplet and it all worked